# React Router: How to render different components with the same route conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

How can I render different components with the same route path with React router but the slug input types are different(int vs string)?

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={['/music/:category', '/products/:category']} component={List} />
    <Route exact path="/products/:productId" component={Details} />
</Switch
```

I want to render List component when the path is `/products/:category` when the slug is a string. I also want to use the same path to render the Details component when its slug, `:productId`, is an integer.

I was thinking this might work, but it doesn't. This renders Details component whether or not the condition.

```
{pathname.includes('/products') && typeof parseInt(pathname.split('/products/')[1]) === 'number'
  ? (
    <Route exact path="/products/:id" component={Details} />
  ) : (
    <Route exact path={['/music/:slug', '/products/:slug']} component={List} />
)}
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can use a parent component to check the type of the param and pass it to the sub component. atm I don't know a better solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of render props of Route to validate the params.

```
<Route
    path="/products/:id"
    render={({ match: { params: { id } } }) => {
      if(isNaN(id) {
        <Route exact path={['/music/:slug', '/products/:slug']} component={List} />
      } else {
        <Route exact path="/products/:id" component={Details} />
      }
    }}
/>
```

Comment: This is the answer. See [the associated docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func).

Comment: Thank you Yadab. I really appreciate your help. I changed some lines and made this working: `<Route  path={['/music/:slug', '/products/:slug']} render={({ match: { params: { id } } }) => {if(isNaN(id) {return <List />} else { return <Details /> }}}/>`